# CONTAINS predicate in SQL Server 2008 nor returning all the rows that it should

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, contains

## Background

In SQL Server 2008, I'm using a Full Text Index on a column named boatType on a table named boats.

The boatType field contains a comma separated list of boatType to which a boat belongs. For example "multihull,trimaran,cruiser".

My SQL query that does the search uses the CONTAINS predicate like this:

CONTAINS(boatType, '"multihull"')

## The problem

Everything was working fine until recently I noticed a particular row was not getting returned, however, other rows that had exactly the same data were getting returned.

## The short term solution

I tried rebuilding the index by removing Full Text Indexing from the boatType column, then re-adding it. I waited for the index to re-populate and that fixed the problem i.e. all expected rows were returned.

## What's the long term solution?

OK, so problem fixed in the short term, but if this happens once it can happen again.

I've assumed (perhaps wrongly) that the "change tracking = automatic" setting on the Full Text Index means that any updates to the data cause an automatic update of the index.

I have not set any population schedules up as I've assumed that I don't need to if I'm using "change tracking = automatic". Again, perhaps I'm wrong.

In support of my assumptions above, new data that's added to the database or changed does seem to trigger an update of the index as most of the rows that should appear in searches do appear. It's just  minority.

What's the best thing to do here?

Comment: Perhaps better suited to DBA, since it's a very focused question.

Comment: Ideally (well, properly) you should not be representing the boat types with a comma-separated list.  I'd have a boat type table and a many-to-many mapping table between boats and boat type.

Comment: I agree with @pst. I have a suggestion though (it's not an answer so I write it in as a comment: create a lookup table for boat types, and then, either create a connection table or replace the comma-seperated text with integer ID's and use a split function so you can use inner joins on that column.

Comment: Just a tip: I think you should not store boats as comma separated. You'd better normalize this relation by creating table boats(boatId,boatName,...,ownerId). Though it's not an answer to your question.

Comment: I agree the current structuring of the table isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the fulltext index being updated in parallel with updates to the indexed data, from the [MS Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575%28v=sql.100%29.aspx),

> The full-text index is updated in the background, however, so
>   propagated changes might not be reflected immediately in the index.

If you require the boat type search to be 100% uptodate, create a table of boat types and a many-to-many mapping table joining boat to boat type.

Comment: Thanks Will - that sounds like a perfect solution, but one that'll take a while to implement as there are a lot of parts of my application that'll need changes. Is there possibly an interim solution that makes the Full Text Index update more regularly than it currently does (it doesnt have to be bang up to date - even a few hours behind would do - but this particular issue the index still hadn't updated a week after the data had changed) and the full index population only takes a few minutes in comparison.